# how to merge consecutive DatetimeIndex?

Tags: pandas

The original Series is

```
2019-02-09 23:04:33                        [9]
2019-02-09 23:04:34                    [7, 10]
2019-02-09 23:05:41    [0, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16]
2019-02-09 23:05:42    [0, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16]
2019-02-09 23:07:41                   [12, 16]
2019-02-09 23:09:42                 [1, 3, 15]
```

How to merge the values which have consecutive DatetimeIndex? The output should be

```
2019-02-09 23:04:33                   [7, 9, 10]
2019-02-09 23:05:41  [0, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16]
2019-02-09 23:07:41                     [12, 16]
2019-02-09 23:09:42                   [1, 3, 15]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom lambda function for processing lists in set comprehension and for `index` values is used [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
f = lambda x: sorted(set([z for y in x for z in y]))

df = s.reset_index(name='a')
#consecutive datetimes by 1 second
s1 = df['index'].diff().dt.total_seconds().ne(1).cumsum()
s = (df.groupby(s1)
       .agg(i = ('index', 'first'), a = ('a', f))
       .set_index('i')['a'])
print (s)
i
2019-02-09 23:04:33                     [7, 9, 10]
2019-02-09 23:05:41    [0, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16]
2019-02-09 23:07:41                       [12, 16]
2019-02-09 23:09:42                     [1, 3, 15]
Name: a, dtype: object
```